# IE 8 menu drop down issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, menu

The Menus don't drop down as they did in IE7.Can anyone help…please!?

You have to click on the title for it to show up, otherwise the menu is hidden.

CSS below:

```
#top_nav{ width: 810px; float: left; background: #DADADA; margin: 0; position: relative; z-index: 100; padding: 0;}
#top_nav ul {margin: 0 0 0 10px; padding: 0; list-style: none; float: left; width: 800px; height: 40px; }
#top_nav li {float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: auto; font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 100%; color: #000; line-height: 150%;}
#top_nav li a{text-decoration: none; color: #000; width: auto; display: block; padding: 8px 18px 7px 18px; line-height: 25px; text-align: center; font-weight: normal; }



#top_nav li ul {position: absolute; left: -999em; height: auto; width: 234px; w\idth: 224px; font-weight: normal; padding: 0px 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa; }
#top_nav li li {padding: 0; background-color: #DADADA; font-size: 90%; line-height: 120%;}

#top_nav li li a{line-height: auto; text-align: left; width: 212px; w\idth: 202px; padding: 3px 10px; border-top: 1px solid #aaa; border-left: 1px solid #aaa; border-right: 1px solid #aaa; }
#top_nav li li a:hover{ background-color: #92D400; color: #fff;}

#top_nav li:hover ul ul, #top_nav li:hover ul ul ul, #top_nav li.sfhover ul ul, #top_nav li.sfhover ul ul ul {left: -999em;}
#top_nav li:hover ul, #top_nav li li:hover ul, #top_nav li li li:hover ul, #top_nav li.sfhover ul, #top_nav li li.sfhover ul, #top_nav li li li.sfhover ul {    left: auto;}
#top_nav li:hover, #top_nav li.sfhover, #top_nav a.active{ background-color: #92D400; }

#sub_nav{ background: #002F5F; float: left; width: 810px; margin: 0; }
#sub_nav ul{ float: left; width: 790px; margin: 0 0 0 10px; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
#sub_nav li{ float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 90%; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }
#sub_nav li a{ color: #fff; display: block; height: 105px; padding: 8px 30px 0 30px; text-decoration: none; }
#sub_nav li a:hover,
#sub_nav li a.active{ background-color: #DADADA; color: #002F5F; }

#section_nav{ float: left; margin: 1px 0 0px 0; width: 810px; background: #002F5F; }
#section_nav ul{ float: left; width: 808px; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
#section_nav li{ float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 70%; font-weight: bold; }
#section_nav li a{ color: #fff; display: block; padding: 8px 10px; border-right: 1px solid #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;  text-decoration: none; }
#section_nav li a:hover,
#section_nav li a.active{ background: #92D400;}
#section_nav img{ float: left; margin: 2px 0 0 2px;}
```

---

The dropdowns don't work automatically in IE8 and you also have to click on the title for it to show up.

HTML as listed below:

```
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.1.7.1.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="js/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
var total = jQuery('#slider img').length;
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({
    animSpeed: 1000, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 4000, // How long each slide will show
    directionNav: false,
    effect: 'boxRainGrow'
});

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 500);
                return false;   
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<a name="top"></a>

<div id="wrap"><!-- START OF WRAP -->

    <div id="header"><!-- START OF HEADER -->
        <a href="http://thehub/livelinkprod/llisapi.dll/intranet/9555529/" class="hub"><img src="images/buttons/btn_back_to_hub.png" width="117" height="27" border="0"></a>

        <img src="images/txt/txt_global_energy_transformation.png" width="361" height="43" id="logo">

  <br clear="all">

        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <a href="http://thehub/livelinkprod/llisapi.dll/intranet/9530498//index.htm?nodeid=9530361&vernum=0" target="_blank"><img src="images/headers/New-org-chart.png" width="730" height="162"></a>
                    <a href="http://thehub/livelinkprod/llisapi.dll/fetch/2000/9697/5358303/9288735/appointments-vacancies.html"><img src="images/headers/New-appointments.png " width="730" height="162"></a></div>
    </div><!-- END OF HEADER -->

    <div id="top_nav"><!-- START OF TOP NAVIGATION -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GET Information</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="latest-news.html">Latest news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="appointments-vacancies.html">Appointments &amp vacancies</a></li>
                        <!-- <li><a href="blogs.html">Blogs</a></li> -->
                        <li><a href="change-champions-smes.html">Change champions &amp; SMEs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="stakeholders.html">Stakeholders</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="get-involved.html">GET Involved</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GET Answers</a>
<ul>
     <li><a href="get-answers.html">General</a></li>
     <li><a href="get-answers-structure.html">Service line-specific</a>
</ul>
</li>
                <li><a href="mailto:get@lr.org?subject=Global Energy Transformation - Site Enquiry">GET in touch</a></li>
                <li><a href="service-lines.html">Service lines/functions</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="inspection-services.html">Inspection services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="compliance-services.html">Compliance services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="asset-integrity-services.html">Asset integrity services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="drilling-integrity-services.html">Drilling integrity services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="consultancy-services.html">Consultancy services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="business-development-services.html">Business development services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="business-services.html">Business services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="finance.html">Finance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="human-resources.html">Human resources</a></li>
<li><a href="technology.html">Technology</a></li>
<li><a href="strategic-projects.html">Strategic projects</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div><!-- END OF TOP NAVIGATION -->
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? What behavior do you except from your menus? Could you show us the HTML code?

Comment: Could you give us a link to your code? Or post your code on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ok, will edit my quey with added code - thanks

Comment: Thanks in advance Big00d and Michael

Answer (score 0):

"z-index: x;" resolved my conflict between CSS drop-down menus and a jQuery slider (slideshow/carousel). It was an easy fix to an issue many people seem to be having.

Try putting that under the CSS style for the drop-down ul.

Example

```
.navbar ul .subnav {
display: none;  
z-index: 3; 
}
```

You can play around with the number (x).